# Dynamic list showing same item, even though the populated list are all unique items

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to build a dynamic list of Views.  These Views are populated through a .json file.  Everything in the code is working perfect - the items are being populated correctly and added to a list of items, which are all correct when I access them via index.

However, when I'm populating my view for some reason it keeps showing the second item in the list.  The result I'm getting:
[Item 1]

[Item 2]

[Item 2]

[Item 2]

[Item 2]

```
struct ItemList: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(items){item in ItemRow(item: item)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ItemList()
    }
}
```

In the initalization `ItemRow(item: **item**)`, if i replaced **item** with **items[i]** it will show the correct item.  It's obviously reading each item in the list of items, but for some reason it only showing the second index.

Below is ItemRow, the view I'm adding.

```
struct ItemRow: View{
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            item.image
            Text(item.brand)
            Text(item.model)
            Spacer()
            Button("More"){
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The model itself

```
struct Item: Hashable, Decodable, Identifiable{
    
    private var photoName: String
    var image: Image {
           Image(photoName)
       }
    var id:String
    var type: String
    var brand: String
    var model: String
    var condition: String
    private var jsonDate: String
    
    var purchaseDate: Date{
        let inDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        return inDateFormatter.date(from: jsonDate)!
    }
    var description: String
    
    
}
```

The json script being parsed and loaded into **items**.  This part is working as intended from what I can tell.

```
 var items: [Item] = load("testItems.json")
```

Any help would be appreciated.. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after getting some food in me!

I left the 'id' property empty on the rest of the items.  I'm assuming it wasn't adhering to the Identifiable protocol because of this.